Tool for deployment via series of Powershell Scripts
I am responsible for continuing to develop legacy software. The software is run as a service on a handful of servers. For making a new release of a component of the software the following steps are taken currently:

A Jenkins pipeline checks out a version of the code and builds it
The executable is copied to a specific location on every server
The software is asked to reload the specific component via some shell commands
Some checks are done (by hand) to see whether it runs successfully

I would like to automatise this for several reasons: Saving time deploying, avoid mistakes that easily happen if done manually, making the deployments more transparent,...
It is not difficult to write short Powershell scripts to do steps 2.-4. But which platform can be used to have a nice interface in order to

deploy new releases (and check whether all deployment steps worked well),
redeploy old releases,
check the release history of the different targets and software components?

I took a look at Octopus Deploy. It provides a very nice interface for all these things. However, I do not need most of its features (as the deployment infrastructure is not very modern) so the price seems pretty high for a nice interface to call a bunch of Powershell scripts.
Can you give me some cheaper options that can be used in my case? Since Jenkins and Jira are already used for development, a nice integration into these would certainly be beneficial.


Providing more context about the team and project would help to advise you with the best CI/CD tool.

Well, following your description, most well-known CI/CD tools fits you in your requirement: 1,2,3.

You can wrap all these steps in a well written Jenkinsfile pipeline or Github Actions with more parameters. This would allow you to keep your deploy customizable and reliable.

If you are looking for a simpler CI/CD tool, free (opensource) with a good web interface. You can use Rundeck which provides a user-friendly interface for running scripts and managing deployments. You can add some Ansible scripts to it to facilitate your 1-4 steps.


